# check if is in array a value bigger than zero

Tags: php

How do I check if in my array values is there a value bigger than 0?

Example:

```
array code {'0', '0', '0'}
```

Returns false.

```
array code_ii {'0', '1', '0'}
```

Returns true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

(If one array element is bigger than 0 the entire array sum is bigger than 0 and you can return true)

```
<?php

    $arr = array(0, 0 , 1);


    if(array_sum($arr) > 0)
        echo "true";
    else
        echo "false";

?>
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: I think this is the better answer from me. Thats why I delete my answer. :)

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain I have to say my first thought was also a simple foreach loop, but then this came in my mind

Comment: @Rizier123 And what if the array is `[0, -100500, 1]`?

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk Then you could use `abs()` to get a positive result

Comment: @Rizier123 But how can I use it?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following technique to get the value bigger than zero if present in array.

```
if (max(array(0,1,0)) > 0)
    echo 'Array has value greater than 0';
```

Hope it will solve your problem or task. Thanks, Looking forward for the comments or queries if any.